# Get list of VMs NOT enabled for Replication using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v, replication

I want to monitor the Replication status of all VMs on our Hyper-V.

All our VMs are replicated. When a replication fails OR the VM is removed from replication, I want to know. I found the following link:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33961/Monitoring-Hyper-V-and-Hyper-V-Replica.html

Here, 90% of my job is done. I can get the complete Replication details and get an email automatically. But there is just one issue: **get-vmreplication** simply gives the status of all VMs which are enabled for Replication.

**I want to know the list of VMs which are not enabled for Replication**.

Can you please help me with the PS Script for generating that list?

Comment: And what stops you from writing a script that gets ALL vm's, then removes those with active replication? Or have tan AI write it for you - that is simple enough it may just work.

Comment: Thanks @TomTom, I had the concept in my head but don't know the powershell script. Somehow, it didn't occur to me that I could use AI tools for the syntax now. Dumb moment, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer using ChatGPT:

```
# Get all Hyper-V VMs
$vmList = Get-VM

# Output header
Write-Host "VM Name`tReplication Status"

# Iterate through each VM
foreach ($vm in $vmList) {
    $vmName = $vm.Name

    # Get replication status
    $replication = Get-VMReplication -VMName $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($replication -eq $null) {
        $replicationStatus = "NOT REPLICATING"
    } else {
        $replicationStatus = $replication.ReplicationHealth
    }

    # Output VM name and replication status
    Write-Host "$vmName`t$replicationStatus"
}
```

Comment: Yep. You better get used to that approach - AI may not be there to write complex stuff now and for some time (measured likely in months) - but small stuff like that, you get it debugged faster than writing the question in serverfault ;)

Comment: @TomTom What you mean "*AI may not be there to write complex stuff now and for some time (measured likely in months)*"? When you say "AI may not be there", where is "there" referencing? I agree people with knowledge about something can use ChatGPT to find starting point answers and then refine accordingly for their needs faster than the, I guess, now old school way, of Googling and sifting through the BS to refine accordingly for starting points. I am curious what you mean by that though or if you have a word typo in your human comment.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It is not old school to look up - stuff like the above can be written by AI. I often have ChatGPT write out complete functions. Regex - not my forte, AI can do it. Many boring things are not a "look it up, try to get it working with debugging in an hour" but "tell AI, review, copy, paste" and done in a minute. Too complicated - things get bad, but simple scripts like that... Google is not old school - it is a waste of money because AI can do the whole work way better. And time is money, you know.

Comment: @TomTom Certainly, I agree with your perspective. The aspects of challenges, mistakes, and learning opportunities are especially captivating—I've gained substantial personal growth through this approach. AI proves to be a valuable resource sometimes, providing swifter starting points compared to relying solely on Google. Integrating both methods can expedite the process and amplify precision in refining starting points tailored to specific needs.